# Unterminated dollar-quoted string creating PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, create-function

Using PostgreSQL 12.3, I am having some trouble trying to validate this simple chunk of `plpgsql` code

```sql
create or replace function test() 
returns void 
as $$
begin
  prepare plan as select 1;
  execute plan;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Error is

```
Unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ begin prepare plan as select 1;"
```

I have tried with and without `;` after `end`. I have also tried with `sql` instead of `plpgsql`.
Any idea of whats is wrong?

This is a db-fiddle to quickly test the code:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/KgRZcxXqJs2Lwe284Mj5y/3

Comment: Let me guess, HeidiSQL?

Comment: I would guess that whichever client you're using to run the SQL does not support dollar quoting. You'll need to replace each pair of `$` with a single `'`. Keep in mind if there are any single quotes within the body of the function, you'll need to escape them. As a bonus, consider checking out DBeaver for your SQL client.

Comment: Ok, I see. This is just a client's inability

Comment: J Spratt, thank you for introducing DBeaver, just amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the $$ quoting:

```
create or replace function test() 
returns void 
as $$
begin
  prepare plan as select 1;
  execute plan;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION

 select test();
ERROR:  column "plan" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT plan
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT plan
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test() line 4 at EXECUTE
```

When you run this in the dbfiddle the full error output is:

```
 Schema Error: error: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ begin prepare plan as select 1;"
Schema Error: error: prepared statement "plan" does not exist
Schema Error: error: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ language plpgsql;"
Query Error: error: function test() does not exist
```

The issue is that EXECUTE inside plpgsql is its own command:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

`EXECUTE command-string [ INTO [STRICT] target ] [ USING expression [, ... ] ];`

I would use the plpgsql form. This works:

```
create or replace function test() 
returns void 
as $$
begin
  prepare plan as select 1;
  EXECUTE 'execute plan';
  RAISE NOTICE 'Made it';
  DEALLOCATE plan;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select test();
NOTICE:  Made it
 test 
------
 
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian!

Comment: Is it possible to return multiple rows from an EXECUTE inside the function test? I mean, changing `returns void` by `returns table (...)`

Comment: The docs are your friend. Start here [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html). There you have [looping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) and there you have "The ```FOR-IN-EXECUTE``` statement is another way to iterate over rows: ..."